# How to write equal subset

Tags: sets

I have a unique set `S={1,1,3,3,3}` but from this unique set I can create many combinations like
`{1,3,3,3,1}, {3,3,1,3,1}, ...` I want to write a generalized formula to represent this.  From the below formula I have already tried to find the total combinations:

```
5!/(2!*3!)
```

where 5 is the total number of elements in the set and number of 1's are 2 and number of 3's are 3.  But I want to write this formula in a generalized way.

Comment: check out `Permutations` (and when you are at it, you might like `Subsets`, `Tuples`)

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are asking for.  Do you want the total number of unique permutations of the given set `S`?

Comment: yes i wan that..i know how to find this but i want to write it in a generalized formula

Answer (score 6):

Since you want to count the elements of each of the classes, use `Tally`. With `Last[#]!&`, you define a function that gets the factorials in the denominator:

```
numberOfCases[s_] := Length[s]!/Times @@ (Last[#]! & /@ Tally[s])
numberOfCases[{a, a, b, a, c, b, a}]
```

> 105

That code instantiates the formula $N!/(n_1!n_2!…n_k!)$ where $N$ is the number of elements of the original set and $n_i$ is the number of elements of the $i$-th class.

Comment: Well, you beat me. +1 :-)

Comment: I had too much caffeine today, it is 2:25am here …

Comment: I dont want to write any program it's just a theory. so I need a theoretical generalized formula.

Comment: Then, this is the wrong forum. In any case, I updated my answer to help you out.

Comment: @user2663126 I don't understand.  You already *have* a generalized formula, you just need to populate it from your set `S`.  What else do you want if not a program?

Answer (score 5):

There is a build-in function `Multinomial`. So the code can be more compact and clear

```
numberOfCases2[s_] := Multinomial @@ Last /@ Tally[s]
numberOfCases2[{a, a, b, a, c, b, a}]
```

> 105

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words): the multinomial coefficient 
$$
{n\choose k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_r} =\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_r!}
$$
is the number of distinct ways to permute a multiset of $n$ elements, and $k_i$ are the multiplicities of each of the distinct elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just a reap sow example (noting the discussion may render no relevance to answer):

```
noc[u_] := 
 Divide @@ ({#1!, Times @@ Map[Factorial, #2]} & @@ 
    Reap[Total@(Sow[1, #] & /@ u), _, (Total@#2 &)])

noc[{a, a, b, a, c, b, a}]
```

yields

105

`noc[S]` yields 10